# Django: How to display Validation errors not specific to a field?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have errors raised in the form's clean method (not tied to a field).

How do I display them in the template?

I tried {{ forms.errors }} and {{ form.non_field_errors }} but neither worked.

Comment: `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` should work - it looks like something else might be wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm guessing if you post the relevant code in your question, we'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/), they go in a special field (`__all__`) and should be accessed via the `non_field_errors()` method. At a guess, I'd say that method returns a sequence.

Comment: It returns a <class 'django.forms.util.ErrorList'>, printing the data returns an html formatted string, but it also has the same attributes as a dict.