# Django 1.10 modelform save issue

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am battling with something that should be simple. In fact, I have done this before, and I cannot seem to get my head around what's going on.

All I want to do is save a modelform from my front end...

I'm on Django 1.10

models.py

```
class Information(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fathers
        fields = ('id','first','middle','last','city_of_birth','region_of_birth','country_of_birth',)   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        self.helper = FormHelper()    
        self.helper.form_class='form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-information'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                 FormActions(Submit('dbPostother', 'Save data', css_class='btn btn-success btn-lg', action=".")),
                  css_class = 'col-md-3'
              )
        )
        super(Information, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^dbPostother$',app.views.dbPostother,name='dbPostother'),
```

views.py

```
def dbPostother(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Information(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()                                    
    context = {'year':datetime.now().year}
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Fathers(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = True,default=1)    
    last = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    first = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    middle = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    city_of_birth = models.ForeignKey(CitiesCity,blank=True, null=True)
    country_of_birth = models.ForeignKey(CitiesCountry,blank=True, null=True)
    region_of_birth = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first +" "+ self.last

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'fathers'
        verbose_name = 'Father'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fathers'
```

This should be simple - but the database is not updating...

Thanks

Comment: Presumably, the form is not valid. Are you displaying the errors anywhere in your template?

Comment: add a `else print(form.errors.as_data())` and edit your answer with the resulting output, please :)

Comment: try this:
`if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    print form.errors`.  If it prints a dict of errors, you can know what error is there.

Comment: As shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470637/django-show-validationerror-in-template
If you display your form using `{{ form }}`, validation errors should render on the page.

Comment: I think the `super` call in an overridden methods is supposed to be the first statement.

Comment: print doesn't seem to work for me in views.py

Answer (score 0):

GAH!!! all day... completely missed... needed to add:

```
self.helper.form_action = 'dbPostother'
```